# android, using Room with kotlin, how to add unique constrain on a field

Tags: kotlin, unique-constraint, android-room

per [Annotate indices and uniqueness](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html), seems it could add constrain unique like below,

but got error in AndroidStudio 3 (the editor has red underline saying "unresolved the reference:indices"), :

```
/Users/application/database/DbAuthor.kt
Error:(14, 39) Expecting an element

@Entity(tableName = "author" indices = arrayOf(Index(value = "authorid", unique = true)))
class DbAuthor(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "authorid")
    var authorid: Int? = null,
```

how to add unique constrain on a field when using kotlin?

gradle is like:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    verAndroidSupport = '27.0.0'
    arch = "1.0.0"
    archRoomVersion = "1.0.0"

}
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.20'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


//arch
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:${arch}"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${arch}"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${arch}"
//room
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${archRoomVersion}"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${arch}"

annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${archRoomVersion}"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed `,` after `"author"`
`@Entity(tableName = "author", indices = arrayOf(Index(value = "authorid", unique = true)))`

Comment: getting error : Assigning single elements to varargs in named form is forbidden

Comment: @Entity(indices = arrayOf(Index(value = arrayOf("authorid"), unique = true)))